# Using selenium grid to execute remote code

Tags: selenium, grid, jenkins

We looking to use Selenium grid to parallelize our tests but some of our tests need to run java code local to the testing machine.  In other words as well as automating the browser we also need to run some java code on the test machine.  Are there hooks in Selenium Grid that will allow us to do this?

PS we are also looking at Jenkins to setup our environment.

EDIT: To be clearer, the java code I need to execute does a get from the web application, downloading pdf files that we cannot do with selenium alone.  It then does some processing on those PDF files.  I suppose the processing could be done on the server hub but the downloading can't.  Unless someone can explain how to download a pdf using selenium and save it to a given location?

Comment: Do you need the java code to run along with the tests or to run it before/after completing the build?

Comment: Along with the tests.  It needs to do stuff like: take a screenshot, deal with pop ups and download files and then manipulate the downloaded files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium cannot execute your java code in the remote control machine. It will get executed only in the hub machine. However, taking screenshot, deal with popup, uploading the files in a specific path can be taken care by Grid.

Comment: "However, taking screenshot, deal with popup, uploading the files in a specific path can be taken care by Grid" -> I've just read this, I try to upload file in a specific file, but I don't know how... Do you have a clue ?

Comment: @rap-2-h check this link for details - http://sauceio.com/index.php/2012/03/selenium-tips-uploading-files-in-remote-webdriver/